# Exception in plugin AppDynamics Android Agent Installer 1.1.38

Tags: android, appdynamics

I am unable to install the plugin `AppDynamics Android Agent Installer` from the marketplace of android studio. I'm getting below exception stack trace.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/parser/GradleBuildFile
    at com.appdynamics.androidstudioplugin.installer.BuildGradleFinder.findBuildGradle(BuildGradleFinder.java:19)
    at com.appdynamics.androidstudioplugin.screens.ScreenController.setChosenModule(ScreenController.java:122)
    at com.appdynamics.androidstudioplugin.screens.ModulePickerScreen$2.mouseClicked(ModulePickerScreen.java:196)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:278)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6657)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.parser.GradleBuildFile PluginClassLoader[PluginDescriptor(name=AppDynamics Android Agent Installer, id=com.appdynamics.androidstudioplugin, path=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.2\plugins\plugin, version=1.1.38)] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@405b4138
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:95)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 42 more
```

I tried changing Gradle versions but still tucked here.

Here are my project configurations

```
Android Gradle plugin version   : 3.2.1
Gradle version                  : 4.8.1
Kotin version                   : 1.3.11
Target & Compatible JDK         : Java 8
```

I also have some screenshots attached.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to using a newer version of Android Studio then is supported with the "Android Agent Installer" methodology:

"Android Studio 2.1.0 - 2.9.9, 3.2.1 - 3.9.9 (Not supported: 3.0.0 - 3.2.0, 4.0)" - from https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/end-user-monitoring/mobile-real-user-monitoring/instrument-android-applications/instrument-an-application-with-the-android-agent-installer

Instead, follow these instructions to build using Gradle with the latest version: https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/end-user-monitoring/mobile-real-user-monitoring/instrument-android-applications/instrument-an-android-application-manually#InstrumentanAndroidApplicationManually-gradle-android-studio